# How to use regular expression in visual studio 2022 search box to find 2 strings existing in one class?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have partial classes and some of them are using _logger and some of them not.

I now want to find those classes which are included `partial` and `_logger` strings, no matter where these words are in the class.

How can I search in visual studio 2022?

Comment: FYI `_logger` is not a C# keyword, it sounds like a field name.

Comment: Please don't use the generic VS tag without tagging the exact version of VS that you're asking about.

Comment: Don't need regex for that, just search in "Entire Solution"

Comment: @Charlieface what should I search exactly in Entire Solution ? I say it is two different string in different live of a class

Comment: Sorry do you meant to say you want to find classes which contain *both* these strings, not *either*? If so you should state that

Comment: No regex needed, search directly in "entire solution"